# Netlink sockets for Kernel to Userspace communication

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, ipc, netlink

I need a IPC between kernel and user-space communication. The kernel module should first initiate the communication to user-space module.

I looked into various methods of kernel to user-space communication like IOCTL, char device, Netlink sockets. Because I need kernel to initiate the communication I dropped IOCTL and char device because the control starts from user-space. I only found Netlink sockets with full duplex communication.

But I was not able to find a simple example program in which the kernel originates the call to user-space first. I was only able to find example for User-space originating the call. Can you please point me to books or examples that shows how kernel can initiate a Netlink socket communication to user-space. Thanks!

Comment: Find an existing k-module that does this and download the source?

Comment: Did you see your application or some other code in kernel can subscribe to netlink groups and corresponding  event in kernel is broadcasted to all the subscribers.

Comment: @user7718036 see rtnl_notify() usage in linux kernel source.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to establish a communication between kernel and userspace with kernel initiating the process. I used a char device to send the pid of the userspace module and then create a kernel netlink socket and send unicast message.

Comment: Just curious to know that if there is way to receive netlink message in kernel without specifying the .input target function in netlink_kernel_cfg structure.